# My homemade telescope

Tags: newtonian-telescope

My telescope is blurry and I am not sure why I used a 254mm primary mirror f/5 with a secondary mirror at 62.5 and I also used a 32mm eye piece I know if I stand back 20cm from eyepiece I see a clear image but any closer and it gets blurry can someone tell me what I am missing

Comment: If you can't get any answers here, you might try locating an astronomy club in your location and taking it along there. It might be easier to for someone who can get hands on.

Comment: As a mimimum, please post the source of your components,  how you set the distance between primary and secondary, and what assembly manual (if any) you used.  As it stands we don't even know whether you are using spherical or parabolic mirrors!

Comment: I actually figured it out now thank you for your comments Had a Little Help from one of my teachers so thank you again it was just that I needed to find tune where the focal point would be

Comment: Perhaps you could answer your own question then, describe how to find tune where the focal point is.